# Do sets $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3\} \cup [\pi, 4)$ and $B = (-1, 0)\cup(1, 2)$ have same cardinality?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

I guess I should try to make some bijective function that maps elements from A to B if I want to prove they have same cardinality, but I don't know how to do it. I know hot to prove that sets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$  have same cardinality, but this seems different.

Comment: Both sets contain an interval, what is the cardinality of an interval?

Comment: **Hint**: Note $A=\{0,1,2,3,\pi, 3.5\}\cup(\pi, 3.5)\cup(3.5,4)$: first make a bijection from $A$ to $(\pi, 3.5)\cup(3.5,4)$, then make a bijection from $(\pi, 3.5)\cup(3.5,4)$ to $B$.

Comment: You were probably shown that $\aleph_0 + c=c$, and that $c+c=c$, where $|\mathbb{R}|=c$. There is no need to construct an explicit bijection if you've proven those facts.

Comment: All subsets of $\mathbb R$ with non-empty interior have the same cardinality.

Comment: The Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem may be of help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will present a proof without cardinal arithmetic, only by building bijections (almost) explicitely.

First, it is not hard to see that :

$$A \simeq \{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7\} \cup (-1,0) \cup (1,2) $$
(where $\simeq$ means that two sets are in bijection)

Therefore, the only thing we have to show is that $\{-1\} \cup (-1,0) \simeq (-1,0)$ (then we can iterate this seven times to fit all the stray points into $(-1,0)$).

To do this, let us define :
$$f \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \{-1\} \cup (-1,0) & \longrightarrow & (-1,0)\\
x &\longmapsto & \left\{\begin{array}{cl} x/2 & \text{if } \quad \exists n\in\mathbb N, x = -2^{-n}\\
x & \text{else}\end{array}\right.
\end{array}\right.$$
You can check that this is a bijection, which ends the proof.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $|A\cup B|=\kappa+\lambda$ where $|A|=\kappa$,  $|B|=\lambda$, and $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ Also, the following is correct $$\aleph_0+2^{\aleph_{0}}=2^{\aleph_{0}}$$ Indeed, $$2^{\aleph_{0}}\leq \aleph_0+2^{\aleph_{0}}\leq 2^{\aleph_{0}}+2^{\aleph_{0}}\leq 2\times 2^{\aleph_{0}}=2^{\aleph_{0}}$$ Now, Clearly, $$n+2^{\aleph_{0}}=2^{\aleph_{0}}$$ for every $n\in\mathbb N.$ So, since $|[\pi,4)|=2^{\aleph_{0}}$ so $|A|=2^{\aleph_{0}}$. Also, $|B|=2^{\aleph_{0}}.$ This finishes the proof.